# Плагин gulp-ttf2woff2 стал медленно конвертировать шрифты

Tags: node.js, gulp, шрифты

Раньше плагин gulp-ttf2woff2 быстро конвертировал шрифты. Я несколько месяцев не пользовался своей сборкой. Когда снова ей воспользовался заметил, что шрифты в woff2 конвертируются заметно дольше, иногда даже дольше 5 минут. За пару дней гугления понял, что у этого плагина есть основная версия на C++ и резервная на JS. Я удалял из папки пакета ttf2woff2 папку csrc, это никак не повлияло на работу плагина. Когда удалил папку jssrc, плагин перестал работать. Я сделал вывод, что у меня из-за чего-то стала рабоать резервная версия на JS. Хотелось бы узнать, почему так случилось, и как начать пользоваться основной версией.